# Requirements.txt install numpy before scipy?

Tags: python, azure, numpy, scipy

I am running a python server using Azure and have a requirements.txt file to install the necessary dependencies.  Everything worked fine until I added scipy. On the build I get this first

`Using legacy setup.py install for scipy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.`

Then, once it starts to install it, it installs it before numpy, despite numpy being higher up on the requirements.txt.  I'm not sure what to do, here's my requirements.txt

```
wheel==0.34.2
numpy==1.18.0
bs4==0.0.1
dash==1.12.0
dash-table==4.7.0
Flask==1.1.2
pandas==1.0.4
requests==2.12.4
tweepy==3.8.0
nltk==3.2.2
scipy==1.2.3
```

Answer (score 2):

The order of the dependencies in requirements.txt does not mandate the order in which they are installed

Instead, they are installed in order of dependency. There is probably some other package that depends on scipy in your case.

I believe your problem is that you have run into a dependency hell by overspecifying the dependencies, causing a version conflict somewhere. Only include the dependencies you use in your own code and let pip figure out the transitive dependencies.

Comment: The issue is that scipy requires numpy as a dependency but doesn't install it within its own setup.py .  I have to install numpy before scipy because for some reason with Azure, its using setup.py instead of pip for both numpy and scipy (it uses pip for my other packages).  The error occurs on the installation of scipy I might add I'm not sure if that was clear.

Comment: What Azure service would this be? And if you’re relying on Azure to manage installation for you, you should probably remove scipy from requirements.txt

Comment: Azure Web App.  Azure needs the requirements.txt in order to install the 3rd party libraries.  Part of my webapp utilizes scipy so I need to install it via requirements.txt.  I have no way to install things other than with requirements.txt that is within my knowledge

Comment: I just added sckit-learn instead of scipy and it installed scipy as a dependency, app hasn't fully deployed yet but now I at least have some hope.  Thank you

Comment: The azure app service will just run “pip install -r requirements.txt” [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-configure-python). But remember that this is only the default behavior. You can customize the installation steps any way you want. Sometimes it is easier to start with a more bespoke base image